# How to open exactly one connection for SQLAlchemy engine?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In my application, I create an instance of following class one time and I want to open exactly one connection for one instance of my application. I have tried changing the poolclass argument of the create_engine function to StaticPool or AssertionPool with no luck.

SQLAlchemy always opens two connections per instance of my application and keeps one of the connection idle all the time.

I have also tried arguments like pool_size = 1 and max_overflow = 0 for default QueuePool but I cannot restrict total connections to 1 connection. The [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#sqlalchemy.pool.QueuePool) states about total number of connections: "It follows then that the total number of simultaneous connections the pool will allow is pool_size + max_overflow, and the total number of “sleeping” connections the pool will allow is pool_size."

I am using sqlalchemy 1.1.4 and python 2.7.

Here is my code for the constructor of class I am creating engine:

```
class DBManager(object):

    def __init__(self, connection_string):
        try:
            self.engine = create_engine(
                connection_string,
                poolclass=StaticPool
                )
        except NoSuchModuleError as module_error:
            logging.error( str( module_error ) )
            raise
        except OperationalError as oper_error:
            logging.error( str( oper_error ) )
            raise
```

**EDIT:**
I do not want to use NullPool because I do not want to recreate database connection for every transaction. I want exactly one connection open at all times.

Can somebody please tell what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to restrict the number of connections created by the engine to one by explicitly specifying the `poolclass=QueuPool` in addition to `pool_size=1` and `max_overflow=0` as shown in the following code:

```
self.engine = create_engine( 
    connection_string,
    pool_size=1,
    max_overflow=0,
    poolclass=QueuePool
    )
```